# spectral structure of sinusoidal model

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab

let us consider following code

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 %plot(x);
end
```

as i know  peaks in   Fourier domain represent    at this frequency,which are present in signal,for example let us take  plot of Fourier transform of this signal
let us run this signal

```
y=generate1(3,500,1);
```

and  plot

```
plot(abs(fft(y)))
```

[image]

but clearly it does not shows me  peaks at frequency  given in signal,what is problem?please help me

Comment: Hi, I provided an answer, hope it helps. Can I ask you a question? I encounter very many questions in which people assume that in order to do a spectral analysis you just need a Fourier transform (which is not correct, as explained at the end of my answer). I'm wondering where this assumption comes from. Is this actually teached in time series analyis classes, or in textbooks?

Comment: generally fourier is considered as a elegant way to  analyse signal in frequency domain

Comment: thanks for help and happy new year and merry christmas

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, you haven't given `plot` any specific values for the x-axis, so it just uses the array indices – why should these correspond to frequencies? The frequencies corresponding to Fourier coefficients can be computed like this:

```
f = (0 : numel(y) - 1) / numel(y) * fs;
```

where `fs` is the sampling frequency of your signal `y`. You don't specify the sampling frequency, but from looking at your code it is clear it is the inverse of `N*T/m`. Extending your function to return this information:

```
function [x, fs] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))';
fs = m/(N*T);
wn = randn(length(t),1);
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
end
```

Putting this together,

```
[y, fs] = generate1(3,500,1);
f = (0 : numel(y) - 1) / numel(y) * fs;
plot(f, abs(fft(y)))
```

you get

[image]

If you zoom in, you will see that you have two peaks at the correct frequencies, 100 and 200. But you also have two peaks at 16467 and 16567.

That's because the Fourier transform of a real-valued signal is always symmetric. Usually this symmetry is stated to be around 0, which you get with a different interpretation of the frequencies attached to the Fourier coefficients:

```
f = (0 : numel(y) - 1) / numel(y) * fs;
f(f > fs/2) = f(f > fs/2) - fs;
```

These two interpretations are equivalent with respect to the reconstructed signal. The result:

[image]

Since the frequency vector `f` is no longer increasing, it is better to use `fftshift` for plotting:

```
plot(fftshift(f), fftshift(abs(fft(y))))
```

Zoomed in view on the result:

[image]

**Please note** that a simple Fourier transform is in general not a good way to assess the spectral content of a signal, for two reasons:

1. The discrete Fourier transform treats the signal effectively as periodic, i.e. it assumes the signal continues after the end by repeating the beginning. This assumption will in many cases introduce a discontinuity, which distorts the spectral content. This problem can be solved e.g. by using a [taper or  window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).
2. Especially for noisy signals, the absolute square of Fourier coefficients is a very imprecise estimate of the signal's power. It is better to cut the signal into shorter windows, and average the different estimates from the different windows. See [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_method), or in Matlab, `pwelch`.

Comment: but for  windowed   method,it is also  problem to choose correct width of window,otherwise  there could be poor frequency resolution

Comment: That is true, there's always a trade-off.

Comment: that why i have started to learn wavelet transform  to know some facts about it

Comment: You have the same trade-off between time- and frequency resolution there, only that it is adapted to the frequency. And you also have the problem that time-frequency power estimated from the absolute-square of wavelet coefficients from one wavelet transform can be very noisy.